# Does all power armour increase Strength both at all and beyond 10 points?

Tags: fallout-4

Do all models of power armor increase the character's Strength stat when equipped and if they do, do they still convey this bonus if the character has maximum strength points (10)?

I am asking, because I could swear my carrying capacity increased before, when putting power armor on, but now when I just tried it, it did not. The only difference is that I now have maximum strength.

Comment: Anything that adds to your SPECIAL stats isn't limited to any maximum that I've seen. The easiest way to test is to equip power armor and go into your pipboy to see if your strength increased.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill Sorry, forgot to mention that I did that, will edit.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as it turns out, when entering Power Armour, your strength is SET to 10. I.e. Power Armour gives you maximum strength, affecting carrying capacity as normal. Therefore by having 10 strength you do not benefit from that particular Power Armour bonus.

As a side note - it should be noted that if you have pocketed armour, which increases your carry weight, you do not benefit from that when IN power armour. In other words, if you rely on greater carrying capacity from Power Armour you should consider these points.

Comment: This is true. I have strength of 10 and all of my armor is pocketed. When I enter Power Armor, I actually lose about 30 points in carrying capacity.